# Creative Data Warehouse Database Alias

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, naming-conventions, standards

Currently, my company is looking for a creative, yet descriptive, name for our data warehouse database server.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Store (with Store having double-meaning... "can you pick up something at the Store?")

Pandora ("the box containing all secrets... don't open that box! Touch at your own risk!")

Answer (score 2):

At work, we use the best name "DataWarehouse". At home though, I went with "AllYourDataAreBelongToUs"

Answer (score 1):

ETLBox - Creative - meh , Descriptive - kinda, Short - yep!

Or just go for "WeDeserveARaise" and then talk about the server a lot ;-)